# Rank 3 tensor multiplied by vectors

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, vectors, tensor-products

Some background before the math:

I am reading a [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022519303000791) that, in its appendix, looks at chemical reactions of the form
$$X_i+Y_i\overset{k_i^+}{\underset{k_i^-}{\rightleftharpoons}} Z_i$$
where species $X_i$ and $Y_i$ reversibly combine to make species $Z_i$ with forward rate constant $k_i^+$ and reverse rate constant $k_i^-$. The paper analyzes many coupled reactions of this form, where the $Z_i$ of reaction $i$ could be $X_j$ or even $Z_j$ for some other reaction $j$.

The paper uses the [law of mass action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_mass_action) to obtain differential equations for the concentrations of the various species:
\begin{align}
\frac{\text dX_i}{\text dt}=k_i^-Z_i-k_i^+X_iY_i \\\\
\frac{\text dY_i}{\text dt}=k_i^-Z_i-k_i^+X_iY_i \\\\
\frac{\text dZ_i}{\text dt}=k_i^+X_iY_i-k_i^-Z_i
\end{align}
where coupled reactions are combined into a single differential equation. For example, if we have two reactions
$$A_i+B_i\overset{k_i^+}{\underset{k_i^-}{\rightleftharpoons}} C_i$$
$$A_j+B_j\overset{k_j^+}{\underset{k_j^-}{\rightleftharpoons}} C_j$$
and $C_i=C_j$, then we have
$$\frac{\text dC_i}{\text dt}=k_i^+A_iB_i+k_j^+A_jB_j-(k_i^-+k_j^-)C_i$$

---

The paper states at the beginning of section A4:

> Using the law of mass action, the kinetic schemes
>   presented above can be formulated in terms of a set of coupled ordinary differential equations. It suffices to give these equations in the shorthand form
>
> $$\frac{\text d\mathbf u}{\text dt}=\mathbf A\mathbf u+\mathbf B\mathbf u\mathbf u$$
>   $$\mathbf u=\mathbf u_0 \text{ at } t=0$$
>   where $\mathbf u$ is the vector of species concentrations, $\mathbf A$ is a matrix specifying the reverse reaction steps, and $\mathbf B$ is a rank 3 tensor specifying the forward reaction steps.

I understand the $\mathbf A\mathbf u$ term, but I am having more trouble understanding the $\mathbf B\mathbf u\mathbf u$ term. I understand that each of the forward reaction terms involve a product of $XY$. So I guess the $\mathbf u\mathbf u$ product is a sort of outer product that gives us a matrix with elements that are all possible products of species (correct me if I am wrong about this). But then what does the $\mathbf B$ tensor even look like, and how is it multiplying the $\mathbf u\mathbf u$ term?

Comment: You could consider $B$ as a vector-valued function in two variables that is additionally linear in each variable. I would write $B[u,v]$ instead of $Buv$ to emphasize this functional character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different ways to represent a rank $3$ tensor $B$ but in each case, it must have $3$ indices, so this has to be different from $B_i$ with a single index.
A $3$-tensor $B = B^i_{jk}$ defines, using Einstein's summation convention, the vector-valued bilinear form

$$Buu := B^i_{jk}u^ju^k$$

that can be plugged into your ODE.

In order to understand the connection with the above formulas, 
we need to define $u$ in terms of the variables. Assuming 
$u=(X,Y,Z)$,
i.e. the joint collection of all $X_i, Y_i, Z_i$, we can 
reindex the components of $u$ as

$$u^i = X_i, \quad u^{N+i} = Y_i, \quad u^{2N+i} = Z_i,$$

where $N$ is the dimension of each of $X, Y, Z$,
and
collect all terms that are quadratic in $u$ into a rank $3$ tensor. For instance, the term $k_i^+X_iY_i$ in the expression for $dX_i/dt$ can be used to write

$$B^i_{j,N+k}u^ju^{N+k} = k_i^+X_iY_i$$

from which we find $B^i_{j,N+k} = k_i^+ \delta_{ij}\delta_{ik}$ using the Kronecker $\delta$ notation.

Comment: $\mathbf u$ is a vector of all unique species. i.e. all $X_i$, $Y_i$, $Z_i$ etc. These are coupled equations, so it is not the case that if there are $N$ reactions that there are $3N$ elements of the vector $\mathbf u$

Comment: @AaronStevens See the edit.